# Error while running a .py file compiled with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I just compiled a file with PyInstaller and when I run it, it says:

```
Error: Program stoped working
```

My program.py (I know it is very big and it is commented in portuguese):

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
    import base64
    import os
    import pygame, sys, easygui, time, datetime
    from socket import *
    coinse=0
    def resource_path(relative):
        return os.path.join(
            os.environ.get(
                "_MEIPASS2",
                os.path.abspath(".")
            ),
            relative
        )
    def encryption(data):
        BLOCK_SIZE = 32
        PADDING = '{'
        pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING
        EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
        secret = "g5774b1111fdd3ty"
        cipher = AES.new(secret)
        encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, str(data))
        return encoded

    def decryption(data):
        BLOCK_SIZE = 32
        PADDING = '{'
        secret = "g5774b1111fdd3ty"
        DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)
        cipher = AES.new(secret)
        decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, data)
        return decoded




    def asserver():
        global coinse
        address = ('0.0.0.0', 7000)

        server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) #SERVER SOCKET
        server.bind(address) #SERVER SOCKET

        pos=[10,10]
        pos2=[10, 10]
        journey=[10,10]
        white=(255,255,255)
        red=(170, 20, 0)
        black=(0, 0, 0)
        pygame.init()
        screen=pygame.display.set_mode([700,500])
        screen.fill(white)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Multiplayer Game")

        health=100 # Vida
        health2=100 #Vida do oponente
        cool=datetime.datetime.now() # Variável usada para o cool-down
        cool2=datetime.datetime.now()
        cool3=datetime.datetime.now()
        cool4=datetime.datetime.now()
        bef=datetime.datetime.now() # o mesmo que cool(2)(3)(4)
        bef2=datetime.datetime.now()
        bef3=datetime.datetime.now()
        bef4=datetime.datetime.now()
        draw=False #Variável de valor True enquanto o player1 usa um/uma poder/abilidade
        draw2=False
        draw3=False
        draw4=False
        toatk=False #to: variáveis que convertem para draw(2)(3)(4)
        todef=False
        toinv=False
        tosh=False
        atk=False #Variáveis de valor True enquanto o player2 usa um/uma poder/abilidade
        deff=False
        inv=False
        sh=False
        loop2=True
        loop=True
        towin=False
        won=False
        data=None

        font=pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
        font2=pygame.font.Font(None, 35)

        screen.fill([255,255,255])
        screen.blit(font2.render("Press ENTER to start a game!", 1, (0,0,0)), [145, 230])
        pygame.display.flip()
        while loop2==True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                        loop2=False
                        break
        server.listen(1)
        server_socket, x = server.accept()
        while loop==True:
            print data
            if won==" True":
                screen.fill(white)
                coinse=str(int(3000/health2))
                if int(coinse)>60:
                    coinse="60"
                easygui.msgbox("YOU LOST!\nYour enemy had "+str(int(health2))+" health left!\nYou earned "+coinse+"!")
                break
            if health2==0:
                screen.fill(white)
                coinse=str(int(health*2+50))
                easygui.msgbox("YOU WON!\nYou had "+str(int(health))+" health left!\nYou earned "+coinse+" coins!")
                towin=True

            data=server_socket.recv(2048)
            sending=str([pos[0], pos[1], toatk, int(health), todef, toinv, tosh, towin])
            server_socket.send(sending)
            data=data.strip("[").strip("]").split(",")
            data[0]=int(data[0])
            data[1]=int(data[1])
            data[3]=int(data[3])
            sh=data[6]
            won=data[7]
            inv=data[5]
            pos2=[data[0], data[1]]
            atk=data[2]
            deff=data[4]
            health2=data[3]
            screen.fill(white)
            if towin==True:
                screen.fill(white)
                pygame.display.flip()
                break
            if sh==" True":
                black=(0,20,220)
            else:
                black=(0,0,0)
            if deff==" True" and inv==" False":
                black=(0,200,0)
            elif deff==" False":
                black=(0,0,0)
            if atk==" True" and inv==" False":
                bef2=datetime.datetime.now()
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,0,0], pos2, 48)
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,255,255], pos2, 45)
            if draw2==True:
                now=datetime.datetime.now()
                if (now-bef2).seconds<5:
                    red=(0,200,0)
                    if not health>100:
                        health=health+0.01
                else:
                    red=(170, 20, 0)
                    draw2=False
                    todef=False
            if draw==True:
                now=datetime.datetime.now()
                if (now-bef).seconds<3:
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,0,0], pos, 48)
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,255,255], pos, 45)
                else:
                    draw=False
                    toatk=False
            if draw3==True:
                now=datetime.datetime.now()
                if (now-bef3).seconds<4:
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, pos, 10)
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, pos, 9)
                else:
                    draw3=False
                    toinv=False
            else:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, pos, 10)
            if draw4==True:
                now=datetime.datetime.now()
                if (now-bef4).seconds<2:
                    red=(0,20,220)
                else:
                    red=(170,20,0)
                    draw4=False
                    tosh=False
            if inv==" True":
                pass
            else:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, pos2, 10)
            screen.blit(font.render("Your Health: "+str(int(health)), 1, (0,0,0)), [10,10])
            screen.blit(font.render("Enemy Health: "+str(health2), 1, (0,0,0)), [300, 10])
            if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool).seconds>10:
                screen.blit(font.render("Attack", 1, (0,255,0)), [300, 50])

            else:
                screen.blit(font.render("Attack", 1, (255,0,0)), [300, 50])
            if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool2).seconds>15:
                screen.blit(font.render("Heal", 1, (0,255,0)), [400, 50])
            else:
                screen.blit(font.render("Heal", 1, (255,0,0)), [400, 50])
            if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool3).seconds>25:
                screen.blit(font.render("Invisibility", 1, (0,255,0)), [470, 50])
            else:
                screen.blit(font.render("Invisibility", 1, (255,0,0)), [470, 50])
            if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool4).seconds>15:
                screen.blit(font.render("Shield", 1, (0,255,0)), [600, 50])
            else:
                screen.blit(font.render("Shield", 1, (255,0,0)), [600, 50])
            pygame.display.flip()
            if journey[0]> pos[0] and journey[1] > pos[1]:
                pos[0]=pos[0]+1
                pos[1]=pos[1]+1
            elif journey[0]< pos[0] and journey[1] < pos[1]:
                pos[0]=pos[0]-1
                pos[1]=pos[1]-1
            elif journey[0]> pos[0] and journey[1] < pos[1]:
                pos[0]=pos[0]+1
                pos[1]=pos[1]-1
            elif journey[0]< pos[0] and journey[1] > pos[1]:
                pos[0]=pos[0]-1
                pos[1]=pos[1]+1
            elif journey[0]> pos[0]:
                pos[0]=pos[0]+1
            elif journey[0]< pos[0]:
                pos[0]=pos[0]-1
            elif journey[1]> pos[1]:
                pos[1]=pos[1]+1
            elif journey[1]< pos[1]:
                pos[1]=pos[1]-1
            if pos[0]-pos2[0] < 1 and pos[0]-pos2[0] > -51 and pos[1]-pos2[1] < 1 and pos[1]-pos2[1] > -51 and atk==" True" and tosh==False:
                health=health-0.04
            if pos[0]-pos2[0] < 51 and pos[0]-pos2[0] > 0 and pos[1]-pos2[1] < 51 and pos[1]-pos2[1] > 0 and atk==" True" and tosh==False:
                health=health-0.04
            if pos[0]-pos2[0] < 51 and pos[0]-pos2[0] > 0 and pos[1]-pos2[1] < 1 and pos[1]-pos2[1] > -51 and atk==" True" and tosh==False:
                health=health-0.04
            if pos[0]-pos2[0] < 1 and pos[0]-pos2[0] > -51 and pos[1]-pos2[1] < 51 and pos[1]-pos2[1] > 0 and atk==" True" and tosh==False:
                health=health-0.04
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    loop=False
                elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if event.button==1:
                        journey=event.pos
                elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key==pygame.K_q:
                        if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool).seconds>10:
                            toatk=True
                            draw=True
                            bef=datetime.datetime.now()
                            cool=datetime.datetime.now()
                        else:
                            pass
                    if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                        if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool2).seconds>15:  
                            todef=True
                            draw2=True
                            bef2=datetime.datetime.now()
                            cool2=datetime.datetime.now()
                        else:
                            pass
                    if event.key==pygame.K_e:
                        if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool3).seconds>25:  
                            toinv=True
                            draw3=True
                            bef3=datetime.datetime.now()
                            cool3=datetime.datetime.now()
                        else:
                            pass
                    if event.key==pygame.K_r:
                        if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool4).seconds>15:  
                            tosh=True
                            draw4=True
                            bef4=datetime.datetime.now()
                            cool4=datetime.datetime.now()
                        else:
                            pass



    def asclient():
        global coinse
        pos=[10,10] #posição
        pos2=[10,10] #posição do inimigo
        journey=[10,10] #posição final
        white=(255,255,255) #cor do fundo
        red=(170, 20, 0) # cor do player1
        black=(0, 0, 0) #cor do player2
        pygame.init()
        screen=pygame.display.set_mode([700,500])
        screen.fill(white)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Multiplayer Game")

        #CLIENT SOCKET
        client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        #CLIENT SOCKET

        health=100 # Vida
        health2=100 #Vida do oponente
        cool=datetime.datetime.now() # Variável usada para o cool-down
        cool2=datetime.datetime.now()
        cool3=datetime.datetime.now()
        cool4=datetime.datetime.now()
        bef=datetime.datetime.now() # o mesmo que cool(2)(3)(4)
        bef2=datetime.datetime.now()
        bef3=datetime.datetime.now()
        bef4=datetime.datetime.now()
        draw=False #Variável de valor True enquanto o player1 usa um/uma poder/abilidade
        draw2=False
        draw3=False
        draw4=False
        toatk=False #to: variáveis que convertem para draw(2)(3)(4)
        todef=False
        toinv=False
        tosh=False
        atk=False #Variáveis de valor True enquanto o player2 usa um/uma poder/abilidade
        deff=False
        inv=False
        sh=False
        loop2=True
        loop=True
        towin=False
        won=False
        data=None


        font=pygame.font.Font(None, 25) #Tipo de Letra pequeno
        font2=pygame.font.Font(None, 35) #Tipo de Letra grande
        screen.fill([255,255,255])
        screen.blit(font2.render("Press ENTER to join a game!", 1, (0,0,0)), [150, 230])
        pygame.display.flip()


        while loop2==True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                        address=easygui.multenterbox("Info:", fields=("IP:", "PORT:"))
                        address[1]=int(address[1])
                        address=tuple(address)
                        loop2=False
                        break
        client_socket.connect(address)
        while loop==True:
            if won==" True":
                screen.fill(white)
                coinse=str(int(3000/health2))
                if int(coinse)>60:
                    coinse="60"
                easygui.msgbox("YOU LOST!\nYour enemy had "+str(int(health2))+" health left!\nYou earned "+coinse+"!")
                break
            if health2==0:
                screen.fill(white)
                coinse=str(int(health*2+50))
                easygui.msgbox("YOU WON!\nYou had "+str(int(health))+" health left!\nYou earned "+coinse+" coins!")
                towin=True

            sending=str([pos[0], pos[1], toatk, int(health), todef, toinv, tosh, towin])
            client_socket.send(sending)
            data=client_socket.recv(2048)
            data=data.strip("[").strip("]").split(",")
            data[0]=int(data[0])
            data[1]=int(data[1])
            data[3]=int(data[3])
            sh=data[6]
            deff=data[4]
            pos2=[data[0], data[1]]
            atk=data[2]
            inv=data[5]
            won=data[7]
            health2=data[3]
            screen.fill(white)
            if towin==True:
                screen.fill(white)
                pygame.display.flip()
                break
            if sh==" True":
                black=(0,20,220)
            if atk==" True" and inv==" False":
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,0,0], pos2, 48)
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,255,255], pos2, 45)

            if draw==True:
                now=datetime.datetime.now()
                if (now-bef).seconds<3:
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,0,0], pos, 48)
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,255,255], pos, 45)
                else:
                    draw=False
                    toatk=False
            if deff==" True" and inv==" False":
                black=(0,200,0)
            else:
                black=(0,0,0)
            if draw2==True:
                now=datetime.datetime.now()
                if (now-bef2).seconds<5:
                    red=(0,200,0)
                    if not health>100:
                        health=health+0.01
                else:
                    red=(170, 20, 0)
                    draw2=False
                    todef=False
            if draw3==True:
                now=datetime.datetime.now()
                if (now-bef3).seconds<4:
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, pos, 10)
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, pos, 9)
                else:
                    draw3=False
                    toinv=False
            else:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, pos, 10)
            if draw4==True:
                now=datetime.datetime.now()
                if (now-bef4).seconds<2:
                    red=(0,20,220)
                else:
                    red=(170,20,0)
                    draw4=False
                    tosh=False

            if inv==" True":
                pass
            else:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, pos2, 10)
            screen.blit(font.render("Your Health: "+str(int(health)), 1, (0,0,0)), [10,10])
            screen.blit(font.render("Enemy Health: "+str(health2), 1, (0,0,0)), [300, 10])
            if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool).seconds>10:
                screen.blit(font.render("Attack", 1, (0,255,0)), [300, 50])
            else:
                screen.blit(font.render("Attack", 1, (255,0,0)), [300, 50])
            if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool2).seconds>15:
                screen.blit(font.render("Heal", 1, (0,255,0)), [400, 50])
            else:
                screen.blit(font.render("Heal", 1, (255,0,0)), [400, 50])
            if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool3).seconds>25:
                screen.blit(font.render("Invisibility", 1, (0,255,0)), [470, 50])
            else:
                screen.blit(font.render("Invisibility", 1, (255,0,0)), [470, 50])
            if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool4).seconds>15:
                screen.blit(font.render("Shield", 1, (0,255,0)), [600, 50])
            else:
                screen.blit(font.render("Shield", 1, (255,0,0)), [600, 50])
            pygame.display.flip()
            if journey[0]> pos[0] and journey[1] > pos[1]:
                pos[0]=pos[0]+1
                pos[1]=pos[1]+1
            elif journey[0]< pos[0] and journey[1] < pos[1]:
                pos[0]=pos[0]-1
                pos[1]=pos[1]-1
            elif journey[0]> pos[0] and journey[1] < pos[1]:
                pos[0]=pos[0]+1
                pos[1]=pos[1]-1
            elif journey[0]< pos[0] and journey[1] > pos[1]:
                pos[0]=pos[0]-1
                pos[1]=pos[1]+1
            elif journey[0]> pos[0]:
                pos[0]=pos[0]+1
            elif journey[0]< pos[0]:
                pos[0]=pos[0]-1
            elif journey[1]> pos[1]:
                pos[1]=pos[1]+1
            elif journey[1]< pos[1]:
                pos[1]=pos[1]-1
            if pos[0]-pos2[0] < 1 and pos[0]-pos2[0] > -51 and pos[1]-pos2[1] < 1 and pos[1]-pos2[1] > -51 and atk==" True" and tosh==False:
                health=health-0.04
            if pos[0]-pos2[0] < 51 and pos[0]-pos2[0] > 0 and pos[1]-pos2[1] < 51 and pos[1]-pos2[1] > 0 and atk==" True" and tosh==False:
                health=health-0.04
            if pos[0]-pos2[0] < 51 and pos[0]-pos2[0] > 0 and pos[1]-pos2[1] < 1 and pos[1]-pos2[1] > -51 and atk==" True" and tosh==False:
                health=health-0.04
            if pos[0]-pos2[0] < 1 and pos[0]-pos2[0] > -51 and pos[1]-pos2[1] < 51 and pos[1]-pos2[1] > 0 and atk==" True" and tosh==False:
                health=health-0.04
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    loop=False
                elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if event.button==1:
                        journey=event.pos
                elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key==pygame.K_q:
                        if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool).seconds>10:
                            toatk=True
                            draw=True
                            bef=datetime.datetime.now()
                            cool=datetime.datetime.now()
                        else:
                            pass
                    if event.key==pygame.K_w:
                        if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool2).seconds>15:
                            todef=True
                            draw2=True
                            bef2=datetime.datetime.now()
                            cool2=datetime.datetime.now()
                        else:
                            pass
                    if event.key==pygame.K_e:
                        if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool3).seconds>25:
                            toinv=True
                            draw3=True
                            bef3=datetime.datetime.now()
                            cool3=datetime.datetime.now()
                        else:
                            pass
                    if event.key==pygame.K_r:
                        if (datetime.datetime.now()-cool4).seconds>15:
                            tosh=True
                            draw4=True
                            bef4=datetime.datetime.now()
                            cool4=datetime.datetime.now()
                        else:
                            pass

    bypass=False
    try:
        s=open(resource_path("profile.data"), "r")
        eprofile=s.readline()
        s.close()
        profile=decryption(eprofile).strip("[").strip("]").split(",")
        coins=profile[0]
        name=profile[1].strip(" ")
        password=profile[2].strip(" ")

    except:
        bypass=True
        coins=0
        name=None
        password=None
        login=["", "", ""]

    if not bypass==True:
        login=easygui.multpasswordbox("Login:", fields=["Name:", "Password:"])

    if not bypass==True and name==login[0] and password==login[1]:
        pygame.init()
        screen=pygame.display.set_mode([700,500])
        pygame.display.set_caption("Multiplayer Game")
        screen.fill([255,255,255])
        pygame.display.flip()
        fontt=pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
        screen.blit(fontt.render("Start a game", 1, (0,0,0)), [20, 55])
        screen.blit(fontt.render("Join a game", 1, (0,0,0)), [20, 95])
        screen.blit(fontt.render(str(coins)+" coins", 1, (255,201,14)), [570, 460])   
        pygame.display.flip()

        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if event.pos[0] > 14 and event.pos[0] < 143 and event.pos[1] > 51 and event.pos[1] < 71:
                        asserver()
                        e=encryption(int(coinse)+coins)
                        s=open("profile.data", "w")
                        s.write(e)
                        s.close()
                        coinse=0
                    if event.pos[0] > 14 and event.pos[0] < 143 and event.pos[1] > 92 and event.pos[1] < 108:
                        asclient()
                        e=encryption(int(coinse)+coins)
                        s=open("profile.data", "w")
                        s.write(e)
                        s.close()
                        coinse=0
    elif bypass==True:
        pygame.init()
        screen=pygame.display.set_mode([700,500])
        pygame.display.set_caption("Multiplayer Game")
        screen.fill([255,255,255])
        pygame.display.flip()
        fontt=pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
        screen.blit(fontt.render("Start a game", 1, (0,0,0)), [20, 55])
        screen.blit(fontt.render("Join a game", 1, (0,0,0)), [20, 95])
        screen.blit(fontt.render(str(coins)+" coins", 1, (255,201,14)), [570, 460])   
        pygame.display.flip()

        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if event.pos[0] > 14 and event.pos[0] < 143 and event.pos[1] > 51 and event.pos[1] < 71:
                        asserver()
                        e=encryption(int(coinse)+coins)
                        s=open("profile.data", "w")
                        s.write(e)
                        s.close()
                        coinse=0
                    if event.pos[0] > 14 and event.pos[0] < 143 and event.pos[1] > 92 and event.pos[1] < 108:
                        asclient()
                        e=encryption(int(coinse)+coins)
                        s=open("profile.data", "w")
                        s.write(e)
                        s.close()
                        coinse=0
    else:
        easygui.msgbox("LOGIN FAILED!")
```

Could someone tell me what to do?

To compile, I am doing this:

```
    pyinstaller.py program.py --noconsole
```

Comment: please show your whole code. just because you think thats where the error is doesnt mean that it is. in the future its probably best to include your whole code and point to what you think is giving the error

Comment: @DTSCode OK, I'll do that.

Comment: does pyinstaller import those libraries?

Comment: I'm almost sure it does

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is no error in this part. Hard to say it because you didn't include full program.

simply you can run your program on terminal if your using linux or Mac as below

```
python <program_name.py>
```

if not you can make executable program
follow this link

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/244378/run-python-in-terminal
```

Comment: Would that run on Windows too?

Answer (score 2):

Find this error

```
File "test.py", line 58
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file test.py on line 58, but no encoding       declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Comment: I think that PyInstaller completly ignores `#coments`

Comment: And I declared the encoding using "`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`", in the first line.